# How to use the Authorization in the Godspeed framework?

Tags: jwt, authorization

How should one configure the JWT object, and what is the process for utilizing it?

Restrictions should be applied to certain workflows for access.

I configured in custom-environment-variables but not working as expected not getting the actual response

Answer (score 0):

Storing the JWT variables in the .env file is a recommended practice to enhance the security of your secret key. Here's how you can declare JWT keys in the [.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sC1d.png).

To access the values of .env variables, refer to [this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkyWO.png) on configuring custom-environment-variables in the `config/custom-environment-variables.yaml` file.

Next, proceed to configure the JWT object in the `http.yaml` file. Specify the 'anthn' variable for the required event using [http.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Aeb.png).